# NUnit v3 alpha in command line: Assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Tags: nunit, nunit-console

I'm trying to run NUnit v3 alpha from command line. Here's my command line:
[...] \NUnit3\nunit-console NUnitAlpha3Experimental.exe /framework:net-4.5

At first, I got this error:

> Errors and Failures Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework,
>   Version=3.0.5378.31152, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=2638cd05610744eb' or one of its dependencies. This
>   assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime
>   and cannot be loaded.

Then I edited nunit-console.exe.config to comment .net 2.0

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <!-- Comment out the next line to force use of .NET 4.0 -->
  <!--<supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />-->
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" />
</startup>
```

I tried these command line (with 4.0 and with 4.5)
[...] \NUnit3\nunit-console NUnitAlpha3Experimental.exe /framework:net-4.0
[...] \NUnit3\nunit-console NUnitAlpha3Experimental.exe /framework:net-4.5

Here's the error message I get:

> Errors and Failures Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.framework,
>   Version=3.0.5378.31152, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=2638cd05610744eb' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Then I tried to edit nunit-console.exe.config to add a new entry for .net 4.5. I tried 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.50710, 4.5.50938, 4.5.50932, 4.5.51641 (all of them are present in control panel -> program and features) and I get a windows popup asking me to install .Net framework 4.5.

Edit: The new entry for .Net framework 4.5* shouldn't work anyways. The unit tests do run even if I get the error message. More info here: https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/issues/42#issuecomment-58709851

Can someone help me with that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem was due to many versions of the dll included with nunit 3.0 (one of each .net framework version) and how it was made available to my assembly. More info here: https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/issues/42#issuecomment-58713975